# Make one field unique depending on another field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table..

```
userid - foreign key
date   - primary key
slot1  - 1st free slot
slot2  - 2nd free slot
slot3  - 3rd free slot
slot4  - 4th free slot
slot5  - 5th free slot
slot6  - 6th free slot
slot7  - 7th free slot
slot8  - 8th free slot
```

All the slots are for the same day, so the user can input different times of the day that he is free.

Now I did this and it worked and now I stumbled upon a problem. I entered some data for one user and now when I try to enter data for another user for the same date I cant because it says it already exists.

How do i make it so that I can have the same user enter multiple dates and also another user enters the same date?... But the same user can't enter the same date twice... How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use a composite `PRIMARY KEY` on `user_id` and `date`.

You may also use a [unique key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) as [Quassnoi suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347371/make-one-field-unique-depending-on-another-field/2347380#2347380), but it really looks like your `date` field alone is not a valid [candidate for a primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key).

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT ux_mytable_user_date UNIQUE KEY (user, date)
```

You should drop you `PRIMARY KEY` on `date`.

You may either create one on `user_id, date` (as Daniel Vassallo suggested), or, if you need to reference this table, create a surrogate `PRIMARY KEY` (say, with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column).

Comment: if u dont mind could u explain this a bit more???

i  dont exactly understand wat uve said here...

Comment: @ananworks: Check out this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key and this: http://help.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp for a basic introduction on unique keys.

Comment: thx... ill chk it and c... will come back if i still need help!!

thanks alot once again!!